# Modify CSS Flexbox Property value via javaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexbox

I am building a website using flexbox for the first time. I came across a situation where I want to change a css property via javaScript or jQuery but I don't know how.

example:

```
#elementId {
/*flex-item*/
align-items: center;
}
```

I want to change to:

```
align-items: flex-start;
```

Is it possible via javaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **Yes you can**.

Here is the syntax.

```
$(Selector).css("style-attribute", "value");
```

Know more on jQuery selectors here, http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Both answers are right. Thank you:) I will accept the fastest in some minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in jQuery:

```
$("#elementId").css("align-items", "flex-start");
```

Comment: Both answers are right. Thank you:) I will accept the fastest in some minutes.